# Is there any way in Admin to know who's online and logged in at the site?

Tags: orocommerce

Sometimes I need to restart the system, and I would like to find out if there is any user/customers currently logged in.  Is there a way to find out in Admin or CLI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data from third-party webmaster tools like google analytics.
For example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However, I was hoping for something easier and local (not 3rd party).  There must be a way to check the database for existing sessions or something.